# Difference Between "View" and "Viewpoint"?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, ambiguity

Suppose the context is people giving their opinions in a discussion.

How are "*view*" and "*viewpoint*" different?  Some dictionaries seem to say they are the same.  What do native speakers think?

Comment: I'm not a native speaker, but when I use the word *view*, I subconsciously focus on *the way* I view that sth., and when I use the word *viewpoint*, I subconsciously focus on *where* I view that sth. from. Kind of when I watch TV, the screen is my view, and where I sit is my viewpoint.

Comment: Which are the dictionaries that say they are the same?

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a case where most natives don't think that hard about these words and use them almost interchangeably.

Having said that, if I were to draw a distinction, I'd say that a *view* expresses what is seen and that a *viewpoint* expresses the position from which the viewing occurs.  Quite often though, what is seen is tightly coupled to where you're looking from.

Therefore somebody's view on a subject lays out their observations and conclusions.  Their viewpoint (in the vernacular- where they're coming from) informs those observations and conclusions.

For example:

Somebody's views on pit bulls might be that they should be made illegal. They might think this because their viewpoint is one of having had a child mauled by a pit bull.

Someone else might have the view that pit bulls are not inherently dangerous and that they can be as sweet or as ill-tempered as any other dog based on how it was raised.  They might think this because they're coming at it from the point of view of having grown up with a pit bull as a family pet that was the "sweetest most well-behaved dog ever".